# Create table with constraint in openedge progress

Tags: create-table, openedge, progress-db

I want to create emp and dept table in openedge progress similar to Oracle db with same structure of table.

Can any one send me the query for that.

Comment: Care to elaborate? What do you mean by: 1) Constraint 2) Similar to Oracle db 3) Same structure of table

Answer (score 0):

Progress Openedge is not SQL.  There is a SQL-92 interface but it is not normally used for anything but reporting.  Nearly all Progress applications are built on the 4GL engine and table creation is usually done from the 4GL perspective.

Trying to force Progress to be SQL will only result in pain, agony and frustration.

Creating tables and indexes is done via the "data dictionary tool".  The specifics of running that tool depend on your Openedge version, the OS you are running on and the licenses that you have available.

If you are fully licensed and comfortable with command line tools ("proenv" if this is Windows) then "mpro dbname -p dict.p" will get you to the dictionary.

If you prefer GUI tools then you presumably have the Eclipse based IDE installed and can hunt around for it in there.

The database does not directly support constraints or foreign keys.  You use application logic and triggers to achieve that kind of functionality.  That can be problematic if SQL is also doing updates because the two languages are unaware of each other -- SQL does not fire 4GL triggers and the 4GL is unaware of SQL triggers.  Trying keep them coordinated usually fails.  (Luckily most SQL use is for reporting -- not for updates.)